# UWP multiple Countdowns with C# and XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, win-universal-app, countdown

I am building an UWP app with C# and XAML. On a custom user control I build a "list" better a ListView with a DataTemplate and a grid inside.
In this grid I have multiple TextBlocks with DataBindings. In each generated row I now want a Countdown Timer from DateTimeOffset.Now to a specific DateTimeOffset in the future (or past - negative values).

I tried to build a class CountDownElement with a text property and called my "countdown" Class with that string. In Xaml I did a DataBinding in a TextBlock to that string.
But it did not change. I think tghe UI doesn't get updated? Is there a different way - maybe to build the countdown only with XAML and bind its value to the a generated value of the ViewModel?

Thanks for your help!

Here my CountdownClass:

```
 public class Countdown
{
    public DispatcherTimer DispatcherTimer;
    public DateTimeOffset StartTime;
    private TimeSpan _time;
    private string _tb;
    private readonly DateTimeOffset _endTime;

    public Countdown(string tb, DateTimeOffset endTime)
    {
        _tb = tb;
        _endTime = endTime;
        DispatcherTimerSetup();
    }

    private void DispatcherTimerSetup()
    {
        DispatcherTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
        StartTime = DateTimeOffset.Now;
        _time = new TimeSpan();
        _time = _endTime - StartTime;

        DispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 1);
        DispatcherTimer.Tick += dispatcherTimer_Tick;

        DispatcherTimer.Start();

    }

    private void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, object e)
    {
        _time = _time.Subtract(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1));
        if (_time <= TimeSpan.Zero)
        {
            _tb = "- " + _time.ToString(@"dd\:hh\:mm\:ss");

        }
        else
        {
            _tb = "  " + _time.ToString(@"dd\:hh\:mm\:ss");
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my Countdown Element where I create a new Countdown Object:

```
 public class ListCountdownElement
{
    public string CountdownElement;

    public ListCountdownElement(Incident incident, int type)
    {
        CountdownElement = "Countdown";

        switch (type)
        {
            case 1:
                if (incident.Resolvebykpiid != null)
                {
                    var endTime = incident.Resolvebykpiid.Failuretime;
                    if (endTime != null)
                    {
                        var c = new Countdown(CountdownElement, (DateTimeOffset)endTime);
                    }
                }
                break;
            case 2:
                if (incident.Firstresponsebykpiid != null)
                {
                    if (incident.Firstresponsesent != null && incident.Firstresponsesent.Value)
                    {
                        CountdownElement.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
                        CountdownElement.Text = "sent";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var endTime = incident.Firstresponsebykpiid.Failuretime;
                        if (endTime != null)
                        {
                            var c = new Countdown(CountdownElement, (DateTimeOffset)endTime);
                        }
                    }

                }
                break;
            case 3:
                if (incident.Resolvebykpiid != null)
                {
                    var endTime = incident.Resolvebykpiid.Failuretime;
                    if (endTime != null)
                    {
                        var c = new Countdown(CountdownElement, (DateTimeOffset)endTime);
                    }
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

This is the IncidentViewModel, where I create the Countdown Element - this is the data, I bind to.

```
 public class IncidentViewModel
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Customer { get; set; }
    public ListStatusBar StatusBar { get; set; }
    public ListCountdownElement Countdown { get; set; }
    public ListStatusLight Status { get; set; }

    public IncidentViewModel(Incident incident, IncidentTypes type)
    {
        this.Id = incident.Ticketnumber;
        this.Title = incident.Title;
        this.Customer = incident.Customerid_account.Name;
        this.StatusBar = new ListStatusBar(incident, type);
        this.Countdown = new ListCountdownElement(incident, type.GetHashCode());
        this.Status = new ListStatusLight(incident, type);
    }
}
```

This is the ListViewModel, where I fetch my Data and create the incidentViewModels and put them to an observable collection:

```
public class IncidentListViewModel
{

    public ObservableCollection<Incident> Incidents;
    public ObservableCollection<IncidentViewModel> IncidentsCollection;

    public IncidentListViewModel()
    {
        IncidentsCollection = new ObservableCollection<IncidentViewModel>();
    }
    public async Task<ObservableCollection<IncidentViewModel>> GetData(string accessToken, IncidentTypes type)
    {
        Incidents = await DataLoader.LoadIncidentsData(accessToken, type.GetHashCode());
        IncidentsCollection.Clear();
        foreach (var incident in Incidents)
        {
            var incidentVm = new IncidentViewModel(incident, type);

            IncidentsCollection.Add(incidentVm);
        }

        return IncidentsCollection;
    }
}
```

This is the xaml.cs of the listcontrol, where I bind to the observable collection:

```
public sealed partial class IncidentListControl : UserControl
{
    private readonly IncidentListViewModel _incidentListVm;
    private readonly string _accessToken;
    private readonly IncidentTypes _type;
    public IncidentListControl(string accessToken, IncidentTypes type)
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this._accessToken = accessToken;
        this._type = type;
        this.ListHeader.Text = type.ToString();
        _incidentListVm = new IncidentListViewModel();
        GetIncidentData();

        //Get Incident Data and update UI
        var period = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60);
        var periodicTimer = ThreadPoolTimer.CreatePeriodicTimer(async (source) =>
        {
            await Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.High,
                GetIncidentData);
        }, period);
    }

    private async void GetIncidentData()
    {
        await _incidentListVm.GetData(_accessToken, _type);
        this.ListViewIncidents.ItemsSource = _incidentListVm.IncidentsCollection;
    }
}
```

And finally the xaml, where I do the binding on the TextBlocks:

```
<ListView Name="ListViewIncidents" Grid.Row="1">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Margin="5">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="150"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Id}" Margin="3" Grid.Column="0" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="12" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" Margin="3" Grid.Column="1" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="12" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Customer}" Margin="3" Grid.Column="2" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="12" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                    <Border Margin="3" Grid.Column="3" Height="10" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black">
                        <Rectangle  Fill="{Binding StatusBar.Color}" Width="{Binding StatusBar.Width}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="10"></Rectangle>
                    </Border>
                   <TextBlock Text="{Binding Countdown.CountdownElement}" Margin="3" Grid.Column="4" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="12" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                    <Ellipse Margin="3" Height="10" Width="10" Stroke="Black" Fill="{Binding Status.StatusColor}" Grid.Column="5"/>
                </Grid>

            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

This is just the relevant part. 
I hope this update helps!

Updated Code:
Countdown.cs

```
public class Countdown : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public DispatcherTimer DispatcherTimer;
    public DateTimeOffset StartTime;
    private TimeSpan _time;
    private string _tb;
    public string Tb
    {
        get { return _tb; }
        set
        {
            if (Equals(value, _tb))
                return;

            _tb = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    private readonly DateTimeOffset _endTime;

    public Countdown( DateTimeOffset endTime)
    {
      //  _tb = tb;
        _endTime = endTime;
        DispatcherTimerSetup();
    }

    private void DispatcherTimerSetup()
    {
        DispatcherTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
        StartTime = DateTimeOffset.Now;
        _time = new TimeSpan();
        _time = _endTime - StartTime;

        DispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 1);
        DispatcherTimer.Tick += dispatcherTimer_Tick;

        DispatcherTimer.Start();

    }

    private void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, object e)
    {
        _time = _time.Subtract(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1));
        if (_time <= TimeSpan.Zero)
        {
            Tb = "- " + _time.ToString(@"dd\:hh\:mm\:ss");
        }
        else
        {
            Tb = "  " + _time.ToString(@"dd\:hh\:mm\:ss");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

ListCountdownElement.cs

```
 public class ListCountdownElement 
{
    private Countdown _countDown;
    public string CountdownElement
    {
        get {return _countDown.Tb ; }          
    }


    public ListCountdownElement(Incident incident, int type)
    {

        switch (type)
        {
            case 1:
                if (incident.Resolvebykpiid != null)
                {
                    var endTime = incident.Resolvebykpiid.Failuretime;
                    if (endTime != null)
                    {
                         _countDown = new Countdown( (DateTimeOffset)endTime);
                    }
                }
                break;
            case 2:
                if (incident.Firstresponsebykpiid != null)
                {
                    if (incident.Firstresponsesent != null && incident.Firstresponsesent.Value)
                    {
                        //CountdownElement = "sent"; --> think about that later
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var endTime = incident.Firstresponsebykpiid.Failuretime;
                        if (endTime != null)
                        {
                            _countDown = new Countdown( (DateTimeOffset)endTime);
                        }
                    }

                }
                break;
            case 3:
                if (incident.Resolvebykpiid != null)
                {
                    var endTime = incident.Resolvebykpiid.Failuretime;
                    if (endTime != null)
                    {
                         _countDown = new Countdown((DateTimeOffset)endTime);
                    }
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

IncidentViewModel.cs

```
public class IncidentViewModel
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Customer { get; set; }
    public ListStatusBar StatusBar { get; set; }
    public ListCountdownElement Countdown { get; set; }
    public ListStatusLight Status { get; set; }

    public IncidentViewModel(Incident incident, IncidentTypes type)
    {
        this.Id = incident.Ticketnumber;
        this.Title = incident.Title;
        this.Customer = incident.Customerid_account.Name;
        this.StatusBar = new ListStatusBar(incident, type);
        this.Countdown = new ListCountdownElement(incident, type.GetHashCode());
        this.Status = new ListStatusLight(incident, type);
    }
}
```

IncidentListControl.xaml.cs, IncidentListControl.xaml.cs and IncidentListViewModel.cs are untouched

**EDIT: Final Version**
new ListCountdownElement.cs:

```
public class ListCountdownElement : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public DispatcherTimer DispatcherTimer;
    public DateTimeOffset StartTime;
    private TimeSpan _time;
    private DateTimeOffset _endTime;
    private string _countdownElement;
    public string CountdownElement
    {
        get { return _countdownElement; }
        set
        {
            if (Equals(value, _countdownElement))
                return;

            _countdownElement = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public ListCountdownElement(Incident incident, int type)
    {
        switch (type)
        {
            case 1:
                if (incident.Resolvebykpiid != null)
                {
                    _endTime = (DateTimeOffset)incident.Resolvebykpiid.Failuretime;
                    DispatcherTimerSetup();
                }
                break;
            case 2:
                if (incident.Firstresponsebykpiid != null)
                {
                    if (incident.Firstresponsesent != null && incident.Firstresponsesent.Value)
                    {
                        //CountdownElement = "sent"; --> think about that later
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        _endTime = (DateTimeOffset)incident.Firstresponsebykpiid.Failuretime;
                        DispatcherTimerSetup();
                    }

                }
                break;
            case 3:
                if (incident.Resolvebykpiid != null)
                {
                    _endTime = (DateTimeOffset)incident.Resolvebykpiid.Failuretime;
                    DispatcherTimerSetup();
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

    }
    private void DispatcherTimerSetup()
    {
        DispatcherTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
        StartTime = DateTimeOffset.Now;
        _time = new TimeSpan();
        _time = _endTime - StartTime;

        DispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 1);
        DispatcherTimer.Tick += dispatcherTimer_Tick;

        DispatcherTimer.Start();

    }

    private void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, object e)
    {
        _time = _time.Subtract(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1));
        if (_time <= TimeSpan.Zero)
        {
            CountdownElement = "- " + _time.ToString(@"dd\:hh\:mm\:ss");
        }
        else
        {
            CountdownElement = "  " + _time.ToString(@"dd\:hh\:mm\:ss");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Comment: Only thing we see in your code is that the field _tb is being updated in the CountDown class with nothing else being done. So can you also show us how you are binding this to your UI?

Comment: All right, I updated my post with all the relevant code

Comment: Still not seeing where the UI can ever be updated. If you use 'binding' you should tell the UI that the data has changed, this is normally done with NotifyProperyChanged events. Only thing you do is changing the tb text.

Comment: Yes this is true. But I have no idea, where to do so. This is why I asked. Maybe someone can suggest me a total different solution. It does not need to be solved like I trxed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems you are not triggering the correct event to let the ui know that the text has changed.
The code you are showing also look a bit complex for what you are trying to accomplish...

First make sure that the CountDown class inherits `INotifyPropertyChanged`. When you add that interface you'll also need to add following code to that class:

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

[NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
{
    var handler = PropertyChanged;
    if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

After that, change the _tb field to an actual property, like this:

```
private string _tb;
public string Tb
{
    get { return _tb; }
    set
    {
        if(Equals(value, _tb))
            return;

        _tb = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

**** Important ****

In the dispatcherTimer_Tick event, change the value of Tb ( the property ), NOT _tb the field.

Now you'll need to route that property to the UI, so in the ListCountdownElement class, change the CountdownElement field also to a real property.

```
public string CountdownElement
{ get { return _countDown.Tb; } }
```

Only thing to do is, add a _countDown field of type CountDown and be sure to assign that in your ListCountdownElement constructor.

I guess that should fix it... ( not tested though :) )

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I tryed it, but it did not titally help. I implemented INotifyPropertyChanged in the Countdown Class and chanched _tb to a property as you described. In the dispatcherTimer_Tick event, I change the value of Tb and I started changing the count down Element to a property ... I assume, you ment public string CountdownElement[get{return _countdwon.Tb;}} but then I need to change the Cowntdown Construcor not to take a string as parameter, because the CountdownElement can never be initialized in the ListCountdownElement Constructor. Any idea about that?

Comment: Indeed, was a typo for that property... ( added it now ). What do you mean you can't init the object in the constructor? You already do that: var c = new Countdown... but that c has to be the _countDown field.

Comment: yes, for sure I do. What I ment was the parameter (excuse me... was not quite clear). The Countdown Constructor takes a string. In my Code I init the Countdown Objects with CountdownElement as parameter. But CountdownElement is null, because I cannot init it without a setter. Thats what I was thinking about.

Comment: I would change the constructor of the Countdown class so it only needs the datetime as input parameter. Why do you need to pass a string? I see no need for that in the current code. Or I'm missing something that you are trying to do in the UI.

Comment: Ok sure. I did this and added my code in the question. The UI does not display any countdown. When I try to debug and set a breakpoint after init of ListCountdownElement in IncidentViewModel.cs the Textproperty Countdownelement of Countdown is null. I think because of the Countdown did not start at that point...

Comment: See if you are hitting the notifyprop change event, so set a breakpoint in the Tb setter. And your updated post has twice the code for the CountDown class and not for the ListCountdownElement class

Comment: Sorry. The wrong code in may answer was a copy/paste mistake. I hit the breakpoint in the setter and get an error there:   this._countDown.Tb error CS1061: 'Countdown' does not contain a definition for '_countDown' and no extension method '_countDown' accepting a first argument of type 'Countdown' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Sorry not seeing the error straight away. What line is this error happening? I don't see any use of _countDown in your Countdown class?

Comment: You could put return _countDown?.Tb instead of return _countDown.Tb or check if _countDown is != null. Maybe he doesn't like that...

Comment: Well, I don't know either. Think the ? helped with that issue. But I do not get an UI update. In the setter of TB in the Countdown Class, I habe a value set and assigned to _tb. The OnProportyChanged Event is trieggered, but in the OnProportyChanged Method the PropertyChanged is null.... MAybe this is the problem, Why nothing appears in the ui...?

Comment: Ok try one more thing, change the Tb property to the same name as the one used in the ListCountdownElement, so public string CountdownElement  {  get {return _countDown.CountdownElement ; } } or could be the rerouting of the string property is not working. So other possibility is to also make the CountdownElement an onpropertychanged propert of type Countdown. Instead of now a normal string property. Like I said earlier. A bit of a complex setup for just a countdown. Can't the actual timer code live inside the ListCountdownElement class?

Comment: I treid it, but it did not change anything. The handler in the nProportyChanged stays null and I think, the TB (now CountdownElement) is not routed to the LisCountdownElement Object. Well maybe there could exist a total different solution for building a coutdown timer for each ListItem, but I have no idea at the moment, where to start. - Edit: saw the second part of the answer too late. I'll give that a try as well

Comment: Thank you! Reducing complexity helped! I have put the Countdown Code to the ListCountdwonElement Class, as you suggested and implemented the INotifyPropertyChanged Interface there and now it works! I updated my question with the working code.Thanky a lot!